# Blocking="false" is not working in JDBC Reconnection in 3.4.2

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el, mule-cluster

In JDBC Reconnection strategy implemented blocking as false.. so when we try to deploy the application, even though JDBC connection fails applicaion should be deployed.But Application is not getting deployed in server.

Following is the xml code

```
<jdbc-ee:connector name="FTPDatabase" dataSource-ref="MySQL_FTP_Data_Source"
        validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="0"
        doc:name="Database">
        <reconnect blocking="false" frequency="10000" count="3"/>
    </jdbc-ee:connector>
```

Comment: Isn't the issue stemming from the data source itself instead of the connector? Can the data source initialize even if the remote DB is down?

Comment: Database is down.. So, even if db is down also, to make application up implemented blocking as false.. even then also application is not getting deployed..How to make application up even if remote db is down?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this is not possible in a OOTB Mule application. The main reason being the manner in which Mule handles exceptions.

What you are facing is a System Exception.

> System Exceptions
>
> Mule invokes a System Exception Strategy when an exception is thrown
>   at the system-level (i.e., when no message is involved, exceptions are
>   handled by system exception strategies). For example, system exception
>   strategies handle exceptions that occur:
>
> during application start-up when a connection to an external system
>   fails When a system exception strategy occurs, Mule sends an exception
>   notification to registered listeners, logs the exception, and — if the
>   exception was caused by a connection failure — executes the
>   reconnection strategy. System Exception Strategies are not
>   configurable in Mule

You can read more about Mule's error handling [here](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Error+Handling)

I guess the designers were of the opinion that if you have a DB connector, the DB will be accessible when the Mule application starts up, and in many ways this is a good feature instead of failing silently, it fails loud and fails fast :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reconnecting 3 times, please try the reconnecting forever option. `<reconnect-forever blocking="false" frequency="120000" />`. This way whenever the database connection comes back up, it should be successful.