# is it not possible to deploy mule application in server if database connection fails

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el, mule-cluster

My Database server is down.. When I try to deploy mule application in mule standlone server, application is not getting deployed because jdbc connector could not connect to database..Even if jdbc connection fails to database, that should not stop application to be deployed.How to implement this?

Comment: Isn't this basically the same question you asked yesterday? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30955266/blocking-false-is-not-working-in-jdbc-reconnection-in-3-4-2

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the Datat Source with dummy values.
I guess deployment is getting failed because of DataSource initialization,
not because of Connector